How to resolve "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." in dompurify 3.0.5 in purify.cjs.d.ts
I have an angular project uses "node": "14.17.3". Not sure what changed but all of a sudden I have an issue with dompurify 3.0.5.
Error: export 'sanitize' (imported as 'DOMPurify') was not found in 'dompurify' (possible exports: default)
So what I did was


"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in tsconfig.json
and
import it as >> import { default as DOMPurify } from 'dompurify';
and
added @types/dompurify: ^3.0.2 in package.json


But now I got this issue


dompurify/dist/purify.cjs.d.ts:401:1 - error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements. 401 export = _default;


So I'm forcing it to import it as


import { default as DOMPurify } from 'dompurify/dist/purify.es.mjs';


But not I got this error


Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/purify.es.mjs is not exported from package ..\node_modules\dompurify (see exports field in ..\node_modules\dompurify\package.json)


Any idea how to resolve it? thank you!

Any solutions??

still waiting for answers, but I'm doing my research as well

my problem was that in my package, for some reason, were imported all types from all packages in the root node_modules folder of the monorepo. Even though dompurify was not included in my dependencies, the typescropt system loaded everything. I had to manually add the types I wanted to import in the tsconfig like "types": [] (don't import any type) and my problem was solved.
